# Console.log not showing array content

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an exercise for my coding class that requires to modify a tree in JavaScript, I think the code is right but testing with `console.log`, I can't see the leaves:

```
{
  val: 0,
  son: [
    { val: 0, son: [Array] },
    { val: 3 },
    { val: 0, son: [Array] },
  ]
}
```

I need to know what's inside [Array].

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
console.log(JSON.stingify({array: ['a','b','c']}))
```

This turns an object into an untruncated, readable string which will then be printed onto the console.

You can read more about it and the optional parameters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).